2023 Santa Fe, newly installed tow package, running lights/ tail lights wont work
2023 Santa Fe, newly installed tow package at dealership. Running lights/tail lights won't work on the trailer-
Brake & signal do work..
Any suggestions?  Thank you

If the dealership installed the tow package, take the vehicle back to have the problem addressed.
